# How to traverse a Graph based on the angle between two edges

Tags: algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

I am stuck in a problem regarding Graph traversal based on the angle between two edges. I would like to summarize the problem as follows, given 5 vertices `a,b,c,d,e` and the edges `(a, b)`, `(b, c)`, `(c, d)`, `(d, e)`.

If I want to traverse the graph based on calculating the angle between two edges like for example `angle((a, b), (b, c))`. If my angle is greater than 10 degree I should stop at `b` and start the process again.

What steps do I need to consider to approach this problem having concrete programming structures.

Comment: I am considering to implement it using the normal BFS structure with conditions that if angle > 10 degree, we should go the next directed neighbor and do the same thing.

Comment: What do you mean by "I should stop at `b` and start the process again" ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, when `angle((a,b),(b,c))` returns a value of over some threshold (10, in your example), you should stop traversing the graph.

This means that effectively, this node (`b`) is not helping by connecting the two edges (`(a,b)` and `(b,c)`). It might be useful for some other set of edges, but that specific connection is not available.

What I suggest is swapping the role of edges and nodes. Every edge in `G` becomes a node in `G'` and every node in `G` becomes and edge in `G'` **only** if the value of `angle()` returns a value lower than your threshold.

On `G'` you can now run BFS, DFS or any other algorithm of your liking. When you are done, use the reverse transformation to "translate" your answer back into the original graph in question.